# How should I avoid memoization causing bugs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, state, memoization

Is there a consensus on how to avoid memoization causing bugs due to mutable state?

In this example, a cached result had its state mutated, and therefore gave the wrong result the second time it was called.

```
class Greeter

  def initialize
    @greeting_cache = {}
  end

  def expensive_greeting_calculation(formality)
    case formality
      when :casual then "Hi"
      when :formal then "Hello"
    end
  end

  def greeting(formality)
    unless @greeting_cache.has_key?(formality)
      @greeting_cache[formality] = expensive_greeting_calculation(formality)
    end
    @greeting_cache[formality]
  end

end

def memoization_mutator
  greeter = Greeter.new
  first_person = "Bob"
  # Mildly contrived in this case,
  # but you could encounter this in more complex scenarios
  puts(greeter.greeting(:casual) << " " << first_person) # => Hi Bob
  second_person = "Sue"
  puts(greeter.greeting(:casual) << " " << second_person) # => Hi Bob Sue
end

memoization_mutator
```

Approaches I can see to avoid this are:

1. `greeting` could return a `dup` or `clone` of `@greeting_cache[formality]`
2. `greeting` could `freeze` the result of `@greeting_cache[formality]`. That'd cause an exception to be raised when `memoization_mutator` appends strings to it.
3. Check all code that uses the result of `greeting` to ensure none of it does any mutating of the string.

Is there a consensus on the best approach? Is the only disadvantage of doing (1) or (2) decreased performance? (I also suspect freezing an object may not work fully if it has references to other objects)

Side note: this problem doesn't affect the main application of memoization: as `Fixnum`s are immutable, calculating Fibonacci sequences doesn't have problems with mutable state. :)

Comment: A small comment on style - you can simplify the greeting method with the ||= operator. Like this: def greeting(formality); @greeting_cache[formality] ||= expensive_greeting_calculation(formality); end

Comment: @zaius: That works in most scenarios, but wouldn't work if `nil` or `false` were a valid value.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. It sucks we didn't get more of a discussion happening here. Maybe because there just isn't any other way :) Update me if you come up with any better solutions.

Comment: @zaius: Maybe I'll start a bounty one day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would lean towards returning a cloned object. The performance hit of creating a new string is next to nothing. And freezing exposes implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

I am still 'ruby newbie', and I don't know if you were aware about the difference between '<<' and '+' methods to a String.

```
first_person = "Bob"
puts(greeter.greeting(:casual) + " " + first_person) # => Hi Bob
second_person = "Sue"
puts(greeter.greeting(:casual) + " " + second_person) # => Hi Sue

# str << obj → str
# str + other_str → new_str
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm more after a more general solution.