# Why we should use dup method?

Tags: ruby

In many ruby projects and even ruby itself I've encountered the using of **dup** method. For example, in some project I've met this construction:

```
class Array
  def flush
    self.dup.tap { self.clear }
  end
end
```

The question is why we should use **dup** method i.e. create copy of object instead of just use the same object? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use dup or clone if part of the codebase is written by an idiot that doesn't know you shouldn't modify objects if you can help it (instead, you should create a new object):

```
class Greeter

  def initialize
    @greeting_cache = {}
  end

  def expensive_greeting_calculation(formality)
    case formality
      when :casual then "Hi"
      when :formal then "Hello"
    end
  end

  def greeting(formality)
    unless @greeting_cache.has_key?(formality)
      @greeting_cache[formality] = expensive_greeting_calculation(formality)
    end
    @greeting_cache[formality]
  end

end

def memoization_mutator
  greeter = Greeter.new
  first_person = "Bob"
  # Mildly contrived in this case,
  # but you could encounter this in more complex scenarios
  puts(greeter.greeting(:casual) << " " << first_person) # => Hi Bob
  second_person = "Sue"
  puts(greeter.greeting(:casual) << " " << second_person) # => Hi Bob Sue
end

memoization_mutator
```

In [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675967/how-should-i-avoid-memoization-causing-bugs-in-ruby), the idiot is past-me.

Answer (score 1):

You may alter an object in some method in your code. To keep the object unchanged after this specific method, you should duplicate the object before doing anything to it.

Another reason would simply be to make a copy of an object (yes, that's pretty logical). For instance, you could duplicate some object of an imaginary class Project to fork it into a new independent project.